# Where can I find a complete EE1 reference for tags and their usage?

Tags: ee1, tags

I've 'inherited' an EE1 site (1.7.1) and am trying to make some customisations to it. Nothing major, but I have had almost no exposure to EE tags.

The official EE1 documentation is very thin and nearly all of my searches, although returning what potentially look like good results, end up containing broken links to old EE documentation that doesn't seem to exist any more.

Where can I find an exhaustive and well put together reference to EE1 tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://ee1docs.com/quick_reference.html

and you can see top right button "Download EE1 Docs" at http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/